# is boiling point of the gas cause cooling in expansion process of refrigeration?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, temperature, everyday-life

I have a doubt about expansion process.

Some people say it's an adiabatic expansion, but other say it's something related to the nozzle.

What is the actual cause for cooling in expansion process?

According to me, pressure drop of the gas, takes the gas to its boiling point. Since the boiling point of the gas is very low, cooling takes place.

Am i correct?

Comment: Have you tried Googling "refrigeration cycle?"

Comment: still need more clarity

Comment: You have a heat exchanger (evaporator) with working fluid entering at one  end as a liquid and exiting at the other end as a vapor.  The vaporization/boiling takes place at a constant low pressure and temperature, with heat supplied by the warm air blowing over the outside of the tubing.  The heat balance on the evaporator (heat exchanger) is $\dot{Q}=\dot{m}\Delta H_{vapor}$, where $\dot{Q}$ is the rate of heat removal from the air and $\dot{m}$ is the mass flow rate of working fluid passing through the evaporator.

Comment: @HvacEngineer, as a start, see https://www.swtc.edu/Ag_Power/air_conditioning/lecture/basic_cycle.htm

Comment: Dude its still more deeper, my question is  about throttling process in refrigeration cycle

Comment: The throttling process lowers the pressure, which allows the working fluid to change phase.  It is the heat required to bring about the phase change that is responsible for the cooling:  heat of vaporization!  The nozzle is merely used to lower the pressure on the liquid.

Comment: @ chester miller, it means phase change is due to the  boiling point of gas. am i correct?

Comment: It means that you have lowered the pressure on the liquid sufficiently to allow the liquid to boil at the temperature it has exiting the throttle valve.

Comment: @chester,  since the boiling point of the refrigerant is low, it produces cooling  in throttling process. is this statement can be accepted?

Comment: I wouldn't have expressed it this way.  I would have said that the boiling produces the cooling and the lower pressure allows the boiling to occur.

Comment: @just for clarity dude.Anyway thanks for clarification

Comment: @HvacEngineer, your working fluid (some type of refrigerant) must follow the Antoine equation.  If the pressure of the working fluid drops, the boiling temperature of that working fluid also drops.  Due to this, the hot, high pressure refrigerant immediately boils when it goes through the expansion valve because it experiences a lower pressure.  The heat to boil the refrigerant must come from the refrigerant itself, so the refrigerant temperature immediately drops as a result.

Comment: @HvacEngineer, also see previous answers for a closely related question.  The link is: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287757/question-about-air-conditioning-cycle/288265#288265

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are no contradictions in all those statements.

> Some people say it's an adiabatic expansion.

What they probably mean is that the initial expansion of the coolant at the output of a throttling device does not involve heat exchange with the surroundings, i.e., the cooling occurs due to evaporation - not due to the cooling effect of some external agent.

> other say it's something related to the nozzle

This is a reasonable statement. A nozzle, as a throttling device, restricts the flow of coolant, which causes pressure drop.

> According to me, pressure drop of the gas, takes the gas to its
>   boiling point. Since the boiling point of the gas is very low, cooling
>   takes place.

This is a reasonable summary as well.

Comment: which one will be best answer?

Comment: @HvacEngineer I'd say all answers have a valid point and complement each other, so it would be subjective to rate them. I'd rephrase the second part of your answer to "and as the coolant boils/evaporates, its temperature drops. I'd add that the adiabatic expansion of gas (with no evaporation involved) also decreases its temperature (unless it expands into vacuum).