# Use of throttling device

Tags: thermodynamics

In a refrigerator, when the high pressure gas passes through the condenser, it have a room temperature and high pressure. Now we need to reduce its temperature, so we pass it through throttling device (capillary tube) to expand the gas and reduce the temperature.

But my question is, we just want to expand it and want to reduce its temperature, so cant we directly pass the high pressure gas from the pipe of condensor to a broader pipe. It can also reduce the pressure and hence temperature. So, what's the use of cappilary tube?

Also, if we reduce the pressure of gas, why it only cools. It can also expand to maintain PV = const so that temperature remains constant.

Comment: Yash, your concepts regarding refrigeration are all wrong.  For details on refrigeration, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287757/

Comment: My question is not regarding refrigeration. It is only about purpose of throttling device when the same output can be accomplished without it.

Comment: You need pressure drop in the flowing refrigerant to produce low pressure on the "downstream" side of the expansion valve.  If you expand the piping, the pressure drop goes down, not up.  Also, your "PV = const" equation implies that you are using the ideal gas law.  Refrigerant is NOT an ideal gas, so this equation does not apply.

Comment: If we expand piping, the gas will expand and do work, so its internal energy will drop and temperature will also drop.

Comment: Yash, that is incorrect.  The gas will not do work against itself.  In addition, the reduction in pressure from using your method will be nowhere near enough to cause a substantial amount of refrigerant to boil, very little heat will be absorbed from the environment as a result, and your refrigerator will not do any useful cooling.  Note that a web search for refrigeration will not show your method being used for any device, anywhere in the world.

Comment: One other comment, Yash - at the point where you want to expand the piping, the refrigerant is a hot liquid, not a gas.  My conclusion: you REALLY need to read the article that I gave a link to.

Comment: Ok, so to make it an efficient refrigerator, its pressure is dropped by increasing its velocity and not by increasing its volume. Am I right?

Comment: Also, if we want to increase the velocity, why we need such a long (2m) capillary tube? A small (1cm) capillary tube can also increase its velocity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82586/discussion-between-yash-mittal-and-david-white).

Answer (score 3):

> we just want to expand it and want to reduce its temperature, so cant
>   we directly pass the high pressure gas from the pipe of condensor to a
>   broader pipe. It can also reduce the pressure and hence temperature.
>   So, what's the use of capillary tube?

If we just expanded the pipe, the upstream pressure would drop, i.e., the compressor would not be able to compress the cooling fluid, which is exactly what is needed to produce sharp drop in pressure and quick expansion at the throttle in order to cause cooling.

> Also, if we reduce the pressure of gas, why it only cools. It can also
>   expand to maintain PV = const so that temperature remains constant.

If the temperature is kept constant, $PV$ is constant, but, when the gas expands without any heat added to the system (i.e., adiabatically), the temperature drops, i.e., $PV$ does not stay constant.

Comment: So, if the capillary tube is just to maintain high pressure in compressor side, why it is so long about 2m long. It can be of 1 cm long.

Comment: @YashMittal The action of the capillary tube is different than the action of an expansion valve or orifice. In case of the valve, the pressure drops after the valve. In case of the capillary tube, the pressure drops inside the tube mostly due to high friction. So, the tube has to be long enough to ensure sufficient pressure drop.

Comment: As the fluid enters the capillary tube, it must contract. So how is pressure reduced? Please explain me the journey of gas/fluid from condenser to evaporator. (I am new to this topic, be patient)

Comment: @YashMittal  As the fluid enters the capillary tube, it tries to accelerate to match the flow rate in a wider tube before it - it cannot contract much. The effect of friction is a significant pressure drop that develops across the tube, which is similar to the voltage drop that develops across a resistor. The journey of the fluid through the capillary tube is very complicated - it is a subject of many research papers. For instance, the fluid undergoes partial phase transition from liquid to gas, while it is moving from one end to another, etc.

Comment: One last question, friction inside capillary tube is between which two surfaces? How does it reduce pressure?

Comment: @YashMittal The friction is between the fluid and the walls of the tube. We can think of that friction as a force resisting the movement of the fluid, so, for the fluid to move, there must be a force pushing it forward and such force is developed due to the pressure differential. Think how it would be more difficult to suck liquid through a long thin tube vs. a short wide tube.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the throttling process involves a sharp drop in pressure and expansion of the refrigerant. Its purpose is to convert saturated liquid from the condenser into liquid-vapor mixture at the input to the evaporator. See equilibrium states 3 and 4 in the figure below which shows a Rankine refrigeration cycle. Keep in mind this does not involve ideal gas behavior.

In general we have

$$\Delta h =\Delta u + \Delta Pv$$

Since the process is adiabatic and involves no work we have $\Delta u = 0$ and thus
$$\Delta h = \Delta Pv$$

For the process, the change in enthalpy is zero, $h_3=h_4$, thus

$$P_4v_4 = P_3 v_3$$

It is not, however, a constant enthalpy process. Note the process is shown as hash lines between states 3 and 4 implying the process is undefined between the two states.

Hope this helps
[image]