# Do throttling devices need valves?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, condensed-matter, pressure

Why is it that a throttling device always has a valve leading to it? If in a closed system loop, a cooled gas exists right before the throttling device, shouldn't the sudden decrease in cross-sectional area reduce pressure without the valve, just as good as with it?

Maybe my misunderstanding lies in the operation of the valve. Is it for safety purposes and left open until emergency shutting is needed, or is it actually open and shut according to a timer or sensor in the circuitry so as to keep it "synced" with the position of the fluid circulating through the stages of the system's cycle (like evaporation, condensing, etc.)?

EDIT: Specifically, my question is related to the refrigeration cycle. Is the purpose of the valve to isolate the fluid at the stage leading to it for a while then letting it off to the next. For instance, the valve between condenser and evaporator. Is my understanding that it's shut starting when the compressor does its job until all the heat possible is dissipated in the condenser and ONLY THEN does the valve open so that the other half of the loop (that was sort of vacuumed out by the compressor beast)... i.e. from valve all the way to compressor, due to its low pressure creates the pressure DROP (compressor->valve loop leading to valve->compressor loop), correct? And that after the valve opens the compressor is shut down until all possible heat is taken from evaporator and it is ready to be compressed, when of corse, the valve shuts again and the compressor starts. Rinse, repeat ad infinitum!

Comment: No.  The throttling device causes a fluid frictional pressure drop.  The pressure drop you get with the Bernoulli effect is only a tiny fraction of what is needed.

Comment: There are a lot of refrigeration cycle devices that have no valve between the condenser and the evaporator. Your kitchen fridge probably uses a long capilary tube for this (the capilary tube is pretty much visible if you look for it).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that with "valve" you mean an expansion valve. This is a combination of a simple throttling device ("a tiny hole in an obstruction in the circuit") with a control mechanism that allows to adjust cooling power ("hole diameter") to load.

Your misconception seems to be related to the fact that a refridgerator/air conditioner is actually a continuously operating machine. It is not like an otto engine, which has different temporally separated process steps during one cycle (fuel injection/air suction, ignition, exhaustion), but all the "steps" of the thermodynamic process of a fridge/AC happen at different locations of the circuit, all at the same time. The throttling device reduces pressure in flow direction at one location of the circuit, while the compressor increases pressure again at a different location. The condenser reduces temperature of the medium (giving off heat) and increases its density in flow direction at yet another location, while the evaporator increases temperature (drawing heat from the environment)  and reduces density, again elsewhere.

So a controllable valve (other than the throttling device itself) is definitely not necessary to maintain the process, as opposed to valves in an otto engine, which ensure that the thing is working at all.

Comment: Even if it is continous, does my statement that the expansion valve after the condenser isolates the recently compressed gas molecules in the condenser until they lose their heat and only then allows it back into the evaporator, make sense. Because if the valve was not there then some gas would keep leaking into the capillary tube without losing maximum thermal energy and results would be a liquid at temperature higher than lowest possible in the evaporator.

Comment: Your statement makes sense in an "along the streamline" meaning, but not in a "chronological" meaning. In this sense, a fluid volume as it passes from condenser to evaporator is decelerated **on its way**. But it is **not** stopped for some time, and the released afterwards. The expansion valve as a control device is just ensuring that the refridgeration machine is not operating at full power all the time. Because a cooling process gets less efficient if it is driven further away from equilibrium, and operating at full power would give you very low temps, but also very high energy consumption.

Comment: But you actually **could** operate the fridge with an uncontrolled throttling device. You don't need to control it, for example if you don't expect it to reach a required target temperature any time soon, but you just need "some" cooling (I guess cheap cooling boxes for camping work that way, because they are so underpowered). This is what I meant by saying "a controllable valve is definitely not necessary to maintain the process".

Comment: So is it the deceleration that causes the refrigerant to become a low pressure cool liquid? And if the valve is the decelerator, then is the compressor the accelerator? ALSO, what does "if it is driven further away from equilibrium" mean, in terms of the valve (does driven further away mean the valve is more constricted or less constricted)?

Comment: "driven away from equilibrium" means a situation where the inside of the fridge is already at -50°C and the outside (your house) is at +45°C. Reaching and maintaining this situation will cost you a lot of energy (see the efficiency of the Carnot Cycle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_heat_engine). At least w.r.t. the inside, the expansion valve avoids this situation, because -50°C is a bit heavy for just cooling yoghurt, and it helps reducing cooling power when, say, +5°C is approached.

Comment: "And if the valve is the decelerator, then is the compressor the accelerator". Yes, exactly. But accelerator in the sense of fluid velocity, not in the sense of velocity of individual atoms/molecules. And by the control function of the expansion valve, the amount of deceleration/acceleration is limited to some reasonable value. You could loosely say, like a traffic light that controls traffic velocity sensibly, while a roadworks site reduces traffic velocity in an uncontrolled way.

Comment: I see. So according to which law does the vapour become cool liquid as it enters the evaporator? Does deceleration at the constriction alone cause it?

Comment: For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation . The constriction does not decelerate the fluid **after** the valve, but **before** the valve (just like in the traffic analogy, the traffic is congested before the traffic light/roadworks site). So the **acceleration** and combined decompression after the valve causes molecules to increase their distance (i.e. decrease density, evaporate), and for that, they need energy to surpass their mutual attraction, which they draw from the environment in the evaporator.

Comment: Before the constriction you have a liquid/vapour mixture with high proportion of liquid and low proportion of vapour at high pressure/high temperature. After the constriction you have the same liquid/vapour mixture with high proportion of liquid and low proportion of vapour, but at low pressure, low temperature. The evaporator efficiently draws heat from the environment in order to reduce the liquid fraction and increase the vapour fraction (in other words: evaporate the liquid). At the compressor and condenser, it is the same vice versa.

Comment: The highest possible cooling potential at the evaporator would be if ALL the vapor condensed. How is the vapor to liquid ratio increased to maximum possible? Like physically. A longer/shorter capillary tube, a smaller/bigger cross-sectional area?

Comment: Questions over questions. I think we have already gone a long way togeher with your original question.

Comment: Please. I promise this is the last one.

Answer (score 1):

A picture would help.  In addition, you seem to be assuming that the throttling device can give you the pressure drop that you want under various operating conditions.  This is probably not the case ... hence the upstream valve.  That upstream valve allows you to take a varying amount of pressure drop and makes the associated system "tunable".

Comment: Check my edit. Does it sound right?

Comment: @ElFlea, does this answer your questions?  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287757/question-about-air-conditioning-cycle/288265#288265

Comment: No. You just showed that the cycle is controlled by sensors and that it automatically adjusts the valves.